# Automating a task done on excel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, integer, decimal, permutation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DK6p.png)

I am trying to automate a task done on excel in JavaScript. Here is the step by step explanation of the task:

1. You get a number which is 48 in this case and break into n numbers of part which are equal to quantities which is 10 in this case.
2. You divide each part with the corresponding quantity and the result is the number of sheets.
3. You keep repeating this process and the goal is to minimize the highest value of sheet is 35 in this case.

The result mean 35 sheets will be run to get all 10 quantities. The quantities which require less sheets will be in surplus amount at the end of the production.

Basically added all the quantities and divide each quantity with the sum and multiply with the number. The problem is that if the quantities has a lot of variance, I get decimals in the result and can not figure out a way to get integers which give me these quantities. For example, in the case below, first image shows the result I am getting and second image show the result I should be getting. The number in this case is 20.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtqTf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuvPg.png

I have also tried using permutation but amount of permutation required get to big which makes it difficult to use that logic.

Comment: Can you expand on your first example of 48 broken into 10 parts.  Specifically, 1) the sum of the ratios is 48 which I presume is intentional, and 2) where do the quantities come from?